# Direct link to add user email to share file in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Usually new user has a link for the google drive file. Then new user open the link in the browser and request access to the file. Owner receives email with link to share file with users email. Something like that

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/folderId?usp=sharing_erl&userstoinvite=email@gmail.com&ts=5c0c350a
```

I'm owner of the google drive file, I have users email and I want to create this link programmaticaly. What does **ts** attribute mean?

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically, try reading this documentation about [Manage Sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing). This is one of Drive API that controls who can access to files & folders using an access control list (ACL). Also to enable an email notification, set the parameter `sendNotificationEmail` to `true`.

Comment: I use API, but in this case I need link kind of the link in the email with user request. But without user request.